# Make same effect on every browser tab by Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This question seems to be weird.. but anyway, here it is.. 
I am creating a shopping cart website where I have a Add to Cart button. Onclicking the button, product is added to the cart and simultaneously it checks whether the whole quantity of that particular product in the inventory has gone down to 0 or not. If it is not 0 then the add to cart button is still shown and if it is 0 then it shows "out of stock" instead of the button..

This functionality has been done using jquery and ajax and backend as php.

So far so good. But I did something that made it look weird. I opened up two browser tabs of the same page where the add to cart button is.

When I click the button in a tab the add to cart button gets replaced by "Out of stock"..But the other tab has still the button there.. So although the the quantity of the product is 0, I can still add the product to the cart from the other tab which makes the current quantity to be minus 1. That is absolutely not the thing I was looking for.. And I dont want to use the set_time_limit function in my jquery code to run the same function again...

So what should I do? I hope I explained the thing well and I don't need to put some code to show that..but anyway. I will put some..

To get the cart button from another page..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
                var prid = <?php echo $product_id; ?>; 
                var cat = '<?php echo $cat; ?>'; /*category*/

                var up = {
                action: 'get_cart_div',
                prid:prid,
                cat:cat
                };

                $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "assets/get_cart_div_single_product.php",
                data: up,
                cache: false,
                success: function(r){

                $('.cartdiv').html(r);
                    },
                });

                });
            });
```

To check the availablity.. It is on the same page and running the previous function again

```
function check_cartdiv(prid,cat){


                var up = {
                action: 'get_cart_div',
                prid:prid,
                cat:cat
                };

                $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "assets/get_cart_div_single_product.php",
                data: up,
                cache: false,
                success: function(r){

                $('.cartdiv').html(r);
                    },
                });

                };

<div class="cartdiv"></div>
```

get_cart_div_single_product.php

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']);
if($action == 'get_cart_div'){
    $product_id = $_GET['prid'];
    $cat = $_GET['cat'];

 /*checking the quantity from inventory table by quering*/
/*add to cart functionality is here..*/

if($quantity < 1){
echo 'out of stock';
}else{
echo '<div onclick="add_cart_u('.$product_id.'); check_cartdiv('.$product_id.',\''.$cat.'\');">Buy Now</div>';
}
}
```

Comment: You can use some kind of polling to check for the Add to Cart functionality.

Comment: no I don't want that..It will be costly if a good number of users are on that page concurrently... The server being apache.. I think it's not a good option..

Comment: Other way is to check for multiple tab in a single browser session and redirect to home page.

Comment: With websockets you can implement a push to all browser tabs when the quantity is 0

Comment: I know but can I be able to do something with what I already have..?

Comment: @user3361854: could you post relevant code here, so that we can tune it a bit to solve your issue.

Comment: On the other hand you should check if the quantity is 0 on your server and return an error if the user wants to remove another item

Comment: @dreamweiver : I just did. Check

Answer (score 2):

This problem can not just occur in the two tab scenario as you described. This can also
occur if I open a tab ,and do not do anything for 5 minutes. Meanwhile some other user in other city, buys that item !
Then if I try to buy,it will again show -1.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem :

1. Make your inventory realtime by adding some polling to your website .e.g. an ajax request timed after every 30 seconds interval.
2. Update your data when the event is fired.e.g. when the user presses "Add to cart",  do not directly do the add to cart operation. Instead show a "updating inventory...." message, check the current status,and if it has changed, take action accordingly. e.g. "Sorry, this item is now Out Of Stock".

Comment: hmm.. That is not a bad idea.. the second one..Actually I was already thinking about that.. but I want to solve the issue of not showing the thing simultaneously on every tab as well without polling

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to:

```
Scenario 1: ( If only 1 item left )
```

Lock that item once any user selects that particular item. Let say provide a timeout within which user can buy that product. After timeout release the lock.

```
Scenario 2: ( More than 1 stock )
```

Lock that item once any user selects that and decrease the stock count by 1.